# Сохранение данных массива в базу данных rb php

Tags: php, redbeanphp

Нуждаюсь в помощи.
нужно занести полученные данные массива из регулярок в базу данных. Использую Red Bean PHP.
Ничего не меняется от метода. preg_match или же preg_match_all.
Пробовал выводить каждый элемент массива в отдельную переменную - результата 0

Вот сам код:

```
if (preg_match('/.*?Ник:\s*(.*)\n.*?Сервер:\s*(\d+)\n.*?Организация:\s*(.*)\n.*?Лидер\/Заместитель: (.*)\n.*?Возраст:\s*(\d+)\n.*?Страна\/Город:\s*(.*)\n.*?Дискорд:\s*(.*)\n.*?Ссылка на форумный аккаунт:\s*(.*)/i',$message)) {
    preg_match_all('/.*?Ник:\s*(.*)\n.*?Сервер:\s*(\d+)\n.*?Организация:\s*(.*)\n.*?Лидер\/Заместитель: (.*)\n.*?Возраст:\s*(\d+)\n.*?Страна\/Город:\s*(.*)\n.*?Дискорд:\s*(.*)\n.*?Ссылка на форумный аккаунт:\s*(.*)/i',$message,$matches);
    


    $leader = R::findOne('leaders','id = ?',[$id]);
    if(!$leader) {
    $newUser = R::dispense("leaders");
    $newUser->nick = $matches[1][0];
    $newUser->id = $id;
    $newUser->server = $matches[2][0];
    $newUserr->org = $matches[3][0];
    $newUser->lz = $matches[4][0];
    $newUser->age = $matches[5][0];
    $newUser->lplace = $matches[6][0];
    $newUser->discord = $matches[7][0];
    $newUser->forum = $matches[8][0];
    $newUser->balls = 0;
    $newUser->yellow = 0;
    $newUser->red = 0;
    $newUser->historyyellow = "";
    $newUser->historyred = "";
    $newUser->historyballs = "";
    $newUser->historyall = "";
    $newUser->datestate = date("d.m.Y");
  R::store($newUser);
  

  $vk->SendMessage($peer_id,"✅ Лидер/заместитель " . $matches[2] . " сервера ". $matches[1] . " был успешно занесен в базу данных");
  $vk->request('messages.removeChatUser', array('chat_id' => $chat_id, 'member_id' => $id));
  exit;

    }
    
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Решено.
Оказывается,что RB PHP создает первичную таблицу или индекс с названием id. Я пытался записать свое значение под id. Нужно изменить название с id na user_id